# How to get a time difference between two timestamp in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

I want to get the time difference between *event_timestamp* and *event_prrevous_timestamp* in the big query.

I'm using this

```
SELECT event_name, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(event_timestamp, event_previous_timestamp, day)
```

But it giving error as:  `No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_DIFF for argument types: INT64, INT64, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signatures: TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART); TIMESTAMP_DIFF(DATETIME, DATETIME, DATE_TIME_PART) at [1:20]`

Comment: What is the data type of event_timestamp and event_previous_timestamp columns?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use [`timestamp_diff()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff):

```
select timestamp_diff(event_timestamp, event_previous_timestamp, second)
```

The last argument is whatever units you want the difference in.

EDIT:

If your timestamps are microseconds, just use arithmetic:

```
(event_timestamp - event_previous_timestamp)  / (60 * 1000 * 1000) as minutes_between
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, I tried it already ,But it giving error as: No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_DIFF for argument types: INT64, INT64, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signatures: TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART); TIMESTAMP_DIFF(DATETIME, DATETIME, DATE_TIME_PART) at [1:20]

Comment: @Dixithnaani . . . Then you don't have two timestamps and your question is not what you really want to ask.

Comment: Yeah ,  it worked. I used timestamp_diff(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_previous_timestamp), minute). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Error is telling that data type of `event_timestamp` and `event_previous_timestamp` is `int64` instead of `timestamp`. Please try with PARSE_TIMESTAMP() as below:

```
SELECT event_name, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', event_timestamp), PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', event_previous_timestamp), day)
```

Comment: Yeah , got it. I used  timestamp_diff(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_previous_timestamp), minute).  Thank you

Comment: That's great. You are most welcome. Best wishes.